# Code executing before getJSON completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically. I'm trying to create a little web application which allows one to see the nth soonest ISS passes *with good weather/visibility*. In order to try and accomplish this, I call the OpenNotify API to get the soonest passes for a given Lat/Lon and then call the forecast.io API to get the visibility for the time at the given location. However, I've been having a problem when sending multiple API requests to the forecast.io API for each of the pass times returned by the OpenNotify API where the second request has been returned before the first and, because of this (I think) both of the results come out being the same.

I tried moving from $.getJSON to and $.ajax where I specified async = false (as you can see in the code). But this doesn't appear to solve anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I've put a screenshot of the network requests and the result I get from my code, at the moment, below)[image: Network Requests][image: Results]

```
var checkISS = function(){
    $.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=' + latCont + '&lon=' + longCont + '&alt=20&n=2&callback=?', function(data) {
        issResponse = data['response'];
        issResponse.forEach(function(item){
            riseTime = new Date (item.risetime * 1000).toISOString();
            console.log("RiseTime = " + riseTime);
            riseTimeHour = riseTime.substring(11,13);
            console.log("RiseTimeHour = " + riseTimeHour);
            weatherRiseTime = riseTime.substring(0, riseTime.length - 5);
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + latCont + ',' + longCont + ',' + weatherRiseTime + '?callback=?', 
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: data, 
                async: false, 
                success: function(data){ 
                    $("body").append(riseTime + " time visibility be " + data.hourly.data[riseTimeHour].cloudCover + "<br>");
                } 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try turning caching off?

Comment: Do you mean browser side? I could try it. But because they're two different requests it shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: I tried disabling cache, but alas, to no avail

Comment: Your variables are all globals : you should rewrite `issResponse` -> `var issResponse`, `riseTime` -> `var riseTime`, etc ...

Comment: Is the `data: data,` correct in the inner `$.ajax(...)` call ? Shouldn't it be `data : {something extracted from item},` ?

Comment: Thank you! Modifying the variables did the trick! :)

Comment: You are making ajax call in a loop, so the response of the second call may come before the first...make it a recursive call with success/error function